# Update Quantity and Update Cart Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

Add Cart Vuew

```
def add_to_cart_view(request,pk):
products=models.Product.objects.all()

#for cart counter, fetching products ids added by customer from cookies
if 'product_ids' in request.COOKIES:
    product_ids = request.COOKIES['product_ids']
    counter=product_ids.split('|')
    product_count_in_cart=len(set(counter))
else:
    product_count_in_cart=1

response = render(request, 'ecom/index.html',{'products':products,'product_count_in_cart':product_count_in_cart})

#adding product id to cookies
if 'product_ids' in request.COOKIES:
    product_ids = request.COOKIES['product_ids']
    if product_ids=="":
        product_ids=str(pk)
    else:
        product_ids=product_ids+"|"+str(pk)
    response.set_cookie('product_ids', product_ids)
else:
    response.set_cookie('product_ids', pk)

product=models.Product.objects.get(id=pk)
messages.info(request, product.name + ' added to cart successfully!')

return response
```

Cart View before Checkout

```
def cart_view(request):
#for cart counter
if 'product_ids' in request.COOKIES:
    product_ids = request.COOKIES['product_ids']
    counter=product_ids.split('|')
    product_count_in_cart=len(set(counter))
else:
    product_count_in_cart=0

# fetching product details from db whose id is present in cookie
products=None
total=0
if 'product_ids' in request.COOKIES:
    product_ids = request.COOKIES['product_ids']
    if product_ids != "":
        product_id_in_cart=product_ids.split('|')
        products=models.Product.objects.all().filter(id__in = product_id_in_cart)

        #for total price shown in cart
        for p in products:
            total=total+p.price
return render(request,'ecom/cart.html',{'products':products,'total':total,'product_count_in_cart':product_count_in_cart})
```

Products Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
product_image= models.ImageField(upload_to='product_image/',null=True,blank=True)
price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
description=models.CharField(max_length=40)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

I want that in cart page there will be a field which will take "Integer Input " and Update the Total Price

Present Cart View Image

[image]

How i Want

[image]

I am new and trying and learning so please help me to sort this out

Will i need any new model or views ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

i have an idea
after pushing "add to cart" button redirect to a new page with product form to take ordered quantity .. like this :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div style="text-align:center";>
<h2 style="color: darkcyan;font-family: monospace;font-size: 55px;">Add item to your cart</h2><br>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h5 style="font-size: 20px;color: blueviolet;">{{ product.name }}</h5>
    <input name="ordered_qty" min="1" max="{{ product.quantity }}" type="number" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" required>
    <br><br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="add_item">Add item</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

and then add your view to update counter and cookie (to set ordered qty) and save in cookies

```
def add_to_cart_view(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # take ordered qty and product id to create cookie
        ordered_quantity = int(request.POST.get('ordered_qty'))
        # Update Counter
        if 'product_ids' in request.COOKIES:
            product_ids = request.COOKIES['product_ids']
            product_ids = json.loads(product_ids)
            products_list_ids = [k['id'] for k in product_ids]
        # if pk of product exist in counter don't incremment counter
            if pk in products_list_ids:
                products_count_in_cart = len(set(products_list_ids))
        # else : (new product in cart) increment counter
            else:
                products_count_in_cart = len(set(products_list_ids)) + 1
        else:
            products_count_in_cart = 1
        # Back to home page
        products = Product.objects.filter(quantity__gt=0)
        response = render(request, 'home.html', {'products': products, "products_count_in_cart": products_count_in_cart})
        # Update Cookie by adding product id and qty
        if 'product_ids' in request.COOKIES:
            product_ids = request.COOKIES['product_ids']
            products_list = json.loads(product_ids)
            products_ids_list = [i['id'] for i in products_list ]
            if pk not in products_ids_list:
                products_list.append({'id': pk, 'ordered_qty': ordered_quantity})
                response.set_cookie('product_ids', json.dumps(products_list))
        else:
            response.set_cookie('product_ids', json.dumps([{'id': pk, 'ordered_qty': ordered_quantity}]))
        return response
    else:
        product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
        return render(request, 'add_item_to_cart.html', {'product': product})
```

Finally you can view ordered quantities in any place ..
this is my solution and i applied in my project .. it works fine
Another idea : search how to add sub-template in your home page to add ordered quantities ..